# Multi Sessionfactory In Spring bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, javabeans

I need to have  multi sessionfactories specified in spring bean. But where the problem comes in i need to load these sessionfactories based on some user value. How will i reference the sessionfactory settings in the bean by some name/key when i want to instantiate it.

thanks

Comment: I don't quite get what you want.  Can you make a simple example?

Comment: Hi I have three(maybe more) database connections depending on a user input(a string currently) i need to instantiate a sessionfactory using this value from the user to map to a bean configuration.